# How do I rename my entire project in IntelliJ without having so many manual steps?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ 2019.2

I occassionally mis-name my project during creation.

I have to quit IntelliJ, renaming the folder, opening project again and renaming package and project module manually as well.

Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the discussion on the issue: [Renaming a project in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177495/renaming-a-project-in-intellij-idea)
There are project, module name, name in file system etc that can all be different and can be renamed. Rename of folder can be done in file system,  project, module rename in the Project Structure settings.