# How to rename project at "Recent Projects" at Android Studio 1.0.2?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to change name (title) of project at "Recent Projects" at "Welcome" screen of AS (1.0.2)?

The problem is at one of my projects, but it's covered by NDA, so can not show it here. It was imported into AS from Eclipse. It was at `code` directory and imported as `code` project by AS. I already renamed folder, project to needed name and everything is fine, but `code` still present at 'Recent Projects' and title of Android Studio. It is not critical, but a little annoying :).

[image]

For example, I need to change 'Gradle' to 'SO-gradle'.

This name also is used at windows title

[image]

I found same [question/answer for IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712877/intellij-idea-how-to-rename-a-project-in-recent-projects-list)

but looks like AS override that screen

[image]

**Update:**

As I told previously, I'm able to rename project and its directory, but old name `Gradle` lefts as is at 'Recent Projects" and title. See images bellow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried renaming the .iml file at the root of your project? It should be named `Gradle.iml`.

Comment: did you tried this ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276872/change-project-name-on-android-studio

Comment: @Shywim I'm able to rename project, the problem is only at special case. See *Updated*.

Comment: @MounirElfassi, Thanks, I already used that to rename project, but still have the problem at special case. See *Updated*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it.

That name is stored at `.idea/.name` file. Need to open it and change it there. After need to restart AS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ha. This has been driving me nuts for months! Finally decided to tackle it today. +1